MySQL crendentials written in plain despite using an authentication configuration
I am using vector layers with a connection to a MySQL database, it says that when saving the authentication as a configuration it will encrypt it, so I used that, but when I look into the layer's source, which is also as-is in the .qgs file, the password is written in plain:
MySQL:TableName,host=hostname,port=portNumber,user=Username,password=PasswordInPlainText,tables=tName
I have tried re-creating other configuration files in case my first was wrong, but same result. Is it normal that it doesnt hide it? Is there another way?
This project will be stored on QField Cloud so I'm quite worried about the safety of these credentials.

Does it also end up in a completely new project file?

yes, i tried making a new project and it appears in the .qgs file
